# List of functions with generic parameter

Tags: scala

I'm trying to collate a list of functions that I will then fold on. 
I have done this before, but this time the parameter that these function have is a list of objects that inherit from the same base class.

What's the syntax for this in Scala?

Here's what I have at the moment.

```
val tasks: List[(List[_ <: MyBaseClass]) => String] = List(
  functionOne,
  functionTwo,
  functionThree
)
```

Comment: Why not just `List[MyBaseClass]`?

Answer (score 1):

If each function has its own `T`, then you need `List[(List[T] => String) forSome { type T <: MyBaseClass }]`. If `T` is the same for all functions in the list (but you don't know it in advance), it's `List[List[T] => String] forSome { type T <: MyBaseClass }`. Your current type is the same as `List[(List[T] forSome { type T <: MyBaseClass }) => String]`. Note that because `List` is covariant, `List[_ <: MyBaseClass]` is equivalent to `List[MyBaseClass]`.